# Проблема с обработкой xlsx файла в node js с использоваением exceljs

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel

Столкнулся с проблемой при выполнении программы. Программа должна объединять таблицы из нескольких файлов в одну, однако на выходе получается, что программа несколько раз берет один и тот же файл, вместо другого, например при входе из трех файлов, на выходе программа может выдать данные в порядке 1,1,3

```
const Excel = require('exceljs')
const fs = require('fs')
var entryDir = './entry/'
var exitFileName = 'Formatted.xlsx'
var entryBook = new Excel.Workbook()
var exitBook = new Excel.Workbook()
var exitSheet = exitBook.addWorksheet('Formatted')
fs.readdir(entryDir, (err, files) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err)
  } else {
    for (var i = 0, len = files.length; i < len; i++) {
      entryBook.xlsx.readFile(entryDir + files[i])
        .then(function() {
          var entrySheet = entryBook.getWorksheet(1)
          var tabHeader = entrySheet.getRow(1).values
          exitSheet.getRow(1).values = tabHeader
          entrySheet.eachRow(function(row, rowNumber) {
            var rowArray = row.values
            if(rowNumber != 1){
              exitSheet.addRow(rowArray)
            }
          })
        exitBook.xlsx.writeFile(exitFileName)
        })
      }
   }
})
```

Проблема скорее кроется внутри цикла for, но не понимаю, как ее можно пофиксить?

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю как устроен модуль "exceljs", но у вас есть единый объект "var entryBook = new Excel.Workbook()" который сразу пытается открыть 3 разных файла, и прочитать их. Вам нужно вызывать Промис чтения файла "entryBook.xlsx.readFile" последовательно друз за другом, а не параллельно. Либо создавать для каждой операции чтения, новый объект "new Excel.Workbook()".